# Can´t connecto to SAP Hana with sqlalchemy in python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, hana

So I´m trying to do a simple connection from Python to SAP HANA with SQLAlchemy but I´m gettin this error:
[image]

While my code looks like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select, Column, Integer, String, Float, Sequence, text
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, Session, sessionmaker

engine = engine = create_engine('hana+hdbcli:///username:password@host/tenant_db_name', echo=True, future=True) 
print("connected")
with engine.connect() as conn:
    result = conn.execute(text("select 'hello world'"))
    print(result.all())
```

The error is giving me is correct, I do not have my tenant database in the 30013, I have it in 32015.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually managed to connect succesfully later that day and this is my structure (I´m using a tenant db):

```
db_connection = "hana+hdbcli://Username:Password@Host:port/tennat_db_name"
```

Thanks in regard!

Comment: Hi Diego , thank you for this answer. Can you tell me what versions of sql alchemy are  you using ? 

I am having the same problem of the post and I have the same structure of you in my string conection

Answer (score 0):

You can give the port directly in the connection string. The connection string, that I am using, typically looks something like this:

```
connection_string = 'hana://%s:%s@%s:%s' % (hdb_user, hdb_password, hdb_host, hdb_port)
```

You can find usage examples in [this](https://github.com/mkemeter/public/blob/master/Melbourne%20Housing.ipynb) and [this](https://github.com/mkemeter/public/blob/master/TaxiTrajectories_Updated_20210928.ipynb) Jupyter Notebook. Further information can be found in the [documentation of the SQLAlchemy HANA dialect](https://github.com/SAP/sqlalchemy-hana).